# How can I pass a parameter to a function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

Here is my table structure:

```
-- users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | Martin |
+----+--------+

-- reputations
+----+-------+---------+
| id |  repo | user_id |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | 5     | 2       |
| 2  | 10    | 1       |
| 3  | -2    | 3       |
| 3  | 5     | 2       |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Also I have a function like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS user_repo //
CREATE FUNCTION user_repo(user_id INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE repo INT;
    SELECT SUM(repo) INTO repo FROM reputations WHERE user_id = user_id;
    RETURN repo;
END;//
```

It works correctly when I call it like `SELECT user_repo(2)` *(it returns `10`, (`5 + 5`))*. Now I need to use that function in another query. All I want to achieve is a list of users with their reputations. So this is **the expected result:**

```
+----+--------+------+
| id |  name  | repo |
+----+--------+------+
| 1  | Jack   | 10   |
| 2  | Peter  | 10   |
| 3  | Martin | -2   |
+----+--------+------+
```

How can I get that? I mean how can I use that defined function into this?

```
SELECT u.*, /* that function */ FROM users WHERE 1;
```

Comment: You can call the function in the query like `user_repo(users.id)` although a join might be more efficient depending on your needs

Comment: @serakfalcon Yes it works, thank you. Just for my information, you mean joining with a function? Is that possible?

Comment: Alternate solution without the function: `SELECT users.id, users.name, sum(reputations.repo) as usrrepo FROM users LEFT JOIN reputations ON reputations.user_id = users.id GROUP BY users.id, users.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
SELECT u.*, user_repo(u.id) as repo FROM users u WHERE 1;
```